# need to read xls files to import data, using ADODB.Connection having System resource exceeded

Tags: excel, asp-classic

Hi I'm trying to read a excel file from our web site to importe data to our SQL.

it's working great until this morning on the line

```vb
objConn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=" & path & vattachid &"."&GetFileExtension(filename) & "; ReadOnly=1;"
```

I received this error

```
Error Number         -2147024882
Error Code
Error Description    [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] System resource exceeded.
ASP Description
Category             Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers
```

If I reboot the server it's working fine again...

what I use is this :

```vb
Sub ReadExcel(vvalid)

Dim objConn, objRS, strSQL
Dim x, curValue
DIM vSumQty



Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=" & path & vattachid &"."&GetFileExtension(filename) & "; ReadOnly=1;"

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM A1:AZ1000"
Set objRS=objConn.Execute(strSQL)

/// validating and saving the data

objRS.Close
Set objRS=Nothing

objConn.Close
Set objConn=Nothing

END SUB
```

Any input on what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the excel workbook open when you try to get the recordset from it? There is a known Microsoft bug that causes a memory leak if it is. See here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319998